# Facing issue with custom user authentication and oauth2 in django

Tags: python, django

I am making an application which has protected API and only an authenticated users should have access to it. To make use of the django's powerful authentication, I decided to extend its User model with some extra fields and customised.
I am using the custom user model by extending AbstractUser Model. But Facing below issue while requesting the oauth2 token.
Below is my code:

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    """Extended version of Django User Model"""
    is_email_verified = models.BooleanField(
        verbose_name="Email Verified?",
        default=False, choices=T_N_F_CHOICES, auto_created=True,
        help_text="This flag indicates if the email address is authentic and validated"
    )
    mobile = PhoneNumberField(
        verbose_name="Phone Number", blank=True, null=True, unique=True
    )
    is_mobile_verified = models.BooleanField(
        verbose_name="Mobile Verified?",
        default=False, choices=T_N_F_CHOICES, auto_created=True,
        help_text="This flag indicates if the mobile number is authentic and validated"
    )
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(
        verbose_name="Profile Picture",
        upload_to=settings.UPLOAD_DIR,
        height_field=None,
        width_field=None,
        max_length=None,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['mobile']

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = "MyUser"
        verbose_name = "MyUser"
        verbose_name_plural = "MyUsers"
```

settings.py

```
...
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.AlphaslateUser'
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'oauth2_provider',
    'corsheaders',
    'countries_plus',
    'rest_framework',
    'users',
]
...
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
    ]
}
...
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'oauth2_provider.backends.OAuth2Backend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
)
...
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'oauth2_provider.middleware.OAuth2TokenMiddleware',
]
```

While I am requesting token from the token url, I am facing below error.

```
Internal Server Error: /o/token/
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
packages/oauthlib/common.py", line 436, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: get_full_path
```

If anyone know how to resolve. I will appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the issue in the outhlib code version 1.3.0
Please see [thread](https://github.com/jazzband/django-oauth-toolkit/issues/808) where I came to know this. I degraded the version to 1.2.0 and the issue was resolved.